# How do you represent basic arithmetic using boolean function?

Tags: arithmetic, boolean-algebra

Say you have an arithmetic problem involving two variables, how do you give a Boolean formula for that using standard techniques so that one gets a minimal formula for a given number of quantifiers?

Consider for example a function that decides if $(1)$ $x>y$ or $(2)$ a function that decides $x|y$?

Comment: Hint: how do you add in elementary school?

Comment: Probably this is a stupid question. But curious about quantifier elimination.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the standard reduction from CircuitSAT to SAT.  Equivalently: Use the [Tseitin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseitin_transformation).

I assume you do know how to write a boolean circuit to test whether $x>y$.  If not, consult a textbook.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I 'know' does not mean I am comfortable using quantifiers. Is there a reference? I am thinking there is both a $\forall\exists$ and a $\exists\forall$ version.

Comment: I am mostly interested in how many quantifiers you could minimally use?

Comment: @Turbo, I can't tell what you are asking.  I would advise you to edit your question.  Your question doesn't mention quantifiers at all -- if quantifiers are central to your question, then that needs to be clearly explained in the question.  we can't give you a useful answer if you're not clear about what you're looking for.  P.S.  Please note that the SAT formula that is obtained through my method has only a single quantifier; there are no nested quantifiers.  You can read more about the difference between SAT vs 2QBF.